# Create an Applicative implementation of `Prob` from Learn you a Haskell

Tags: haskell, applicative

## The problem description

It seems that something has changed in Haskell since the publication of Learn you a Haskell for Great Good. When creating `Monads` you not only have to define the `Functor` but also now the `Applicative` implementation.

In Chapter 14 of the book, in the section on ["Making Monads"](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#making-monads), we define a `newtype Prob` like...

```
newtype Prob a = Prob { getProb :: [(a, Rational)] } deriving Show
```

and then its `Functor` instance...

```
instance Functor Prob where
  fmap f (Prob xs) = Prob $ map (\(x, p) -> (f x, p)) xs
```

and then the book goes on to define the `Monad` instance for it...

```
flatten :: Prob (Prob a) -> Prob a
flatten (Prob xs) = Prob $ concat $ map multAll xs
  where multAll (Prob innerxs, p) = map (\(x,r) -> (x,r*p)) innerxs

instance Monad Prob where
  return x = Prob [(x,1%1)]
  m >>= f = flatten (fmap f m)
  fail _ = Prob []
```

but I get an error...

> • No instance for (Applicative Prob) arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
>
> • In the instance declaration for ‘Monad Prob’

I've read that the `Applicative` instance is now explicitly required and created my solution and wondered if it is correct?

## Current attempt at implementing it myself

My implementation is...

```
instance Applicative Prob where
  pure x = Prob [(x, 1%1)]
  (Prob xs) <*> (Prob ys) = Prob ([(f y, p * q) | (f, p) <- xs, (y, q) <- ys])
```

I've done this as the first parameter of the `<*>` could be something like `Prob [((*3),1%2),((+1),1%2)]` so it would seem that each function in the first parameter would have to be applied to every value in the second parameter and that also the probabilities would have to be dealt with somehow.

## Request for answers

Which just seems wrong to me, I don't like that I've pulled out the probabilities like this when the implementation in the book was just automatic and didn't require any of this extra work. I wondered if there is a simpler way to define what I have created or even if this is just wrong in the first place? I feel like there is possibly an `fmap` hiding in my `Applicative` code somewhere but I'm too new to find it myself.

Even better would be if there is an updated resource for these missing implementations which I've, as yet, been unsuccessful in finding.

Comment: LYAH is a great book, but it is sadly out of date. I vaguely recall someone forking the contents in order to update things like this.

Comment: @chepner I have come to learn this over my time of reading it. It makes it interesting trying to get through the examples and stumbling across obstacles along the way. Keeps me on my toes. :D

Comment: Once you have defined your own instance it's good to know if it can be derived. If you enabled `-XDerivingVia` you can write `deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadFail) via WriterT (Product Rational) []`. Uses the fact that [`WriterT [] ..`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html#t:WriterT) has the same runtime representation as `Prob`. [`Product Rational`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Product)  says to use `Rational` with multiplication and 1 (= 1%1) as mempty.

Comment: But it is not limited to functor, applicative, monad. Running the [`:instances WriterT [] (Product Rational)`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:instances) command lists candidates for deriving like `Alternative`, `MonadZip`, `MonadFix`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `Monad` instance for `m`, you get an `Applicative` instance of `m` for free defined by

```hs
instance Applicative m where
    pure  = return
    (<*>) = ap
```

Recall that `ap` is defined by

```hs
ap mf mx = mf >>= \f -> x >>= f
```

Or, using `do` notation,

```hs
ap mf mx = do 
    { f <- mf
    ; x <- mx
    ; return (f x)
    }
```

`Applicative`s are generalisations of `Monad`s. Every `Monad` must also be an `Applicative` in this canonical way. Modern Haskell enforces this by requiring an `Applicative` instance for every `Monad`.

Comment: Ah! OK, that makes sense now. I was getting the hierarchy the wrong way round. And actually, what you have said makes sense as I couldn't help but thinking that my <*> was duplicating a lot of the logic in the Monad instance (multiplying the rationals etc...). Thanks very much.

Comment: @Fogmeister I suspect you did not have the hierarchy the wrong way around. It's just that, unlike some other languages' systems, the "must exist" hierarchy and the "must use in its implementation" hierarchy are decoupled -- an `Applicative` instance must exist for a `Monad` instance to be legal, but either one can call methods from the other in its instance implementation.

Answer (score 2):

LYAH was published long before `Applicative` was made a super class of `Monad`.At that time, the classes were defined like

```
 class Functor where
     ...

 class Functor f => Applicative f where
     ...

 class Functor m => Monad m where
     ...
```

Now, `Applicative` has been inserted between `Functor` and `Monad`:

```
 class Functor where
     ...

 class Functor f => Applicative f where
     ...

 class Applicative m => Monad m where
     ...
```

Before, you would typically define a new `Applicative` instance in terms of existing `Functor` and `Monad` instances. Now, you tend to define `Applicative` in terms of `Functor`, and `Monad` in terms of `Applicative.`

Comment: @DanielWagner "Incorrect" seems strong. The "must" claim you are refuting does not appear in this answer. The answer just claims a way things are "typically done". Personally I'm a little skeptical even of that - I quite often see Applicative defined in terms of Monad. But I don't have enough data to say for certain. Do you?

Comment: @amalloy You are absolutely right. I've deleted my comment, therefore.

Comment: @amalloy @DanielWagner Sure, for existing code it would be easier to define the "newfangled" `Applicative` instance in terms of an already written `Monad` instance. I was under the impression, though I could be (and probably am) wrong, that for types after the F/A/M proposal took effect, the people would write `Applicative` first and then `Monad`.

Comment: @chepner I think in practice Monad is often easier to understand. I'm not really sure why - maybe easier to discharge one wrapper at a time, than to figure out how to combine two wrappers?